# How can I use __del__ in python to add the deleted object to a list before they get destroyed?

Tags: python

I wish to put every instance of the students class that gets deleted by
`del` to be added to my `students_leaving[]` list

```
students_leaving = []
class Student:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name= first_name
        self.last_name= last_name

    # the destructor I wish to redefine:
    #def __del__(self):

john = Students("John", "Smith")
julie = Students("Julie", "Martin")
marc = Etudiant("Marc", "Tremblay")

del marc
assert students_leaving[0] == 'Marc Tremblay'
```

Comment: Sounds like a really, really bad idea. Why?

Comment: It's a class assignment. I felt it was a bad idea too, don't really understand the purpose.

Comment: Adding them to a list would prevent their destruction. Besides that, there's no garantee that `__del__()` will ever be called unless you do it explicitly.

Comment: I know, but is there a way to get a hold of the object before it gets destroyed?

Comment: It's better to use your member functions to implement some logic, rather than a destructor. Or use context managers in some cases https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misunderstand your assignment? No one sane would ever do this.

Comment: Just to make that clear as it is a common misconception: `del` does not delete objects. It removes a reference to an object.